# Change css className of a div with animated transition

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks

I am replacing the className of a div with button. But while doing this, I want to do it with animated transition while className change. In the code below, the className is changing, but without animated transition. How can I add the animated transition while class is changing?

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import classes from "./Card.module.css";
import { ClickAwayListener } from "@mui/base";

function Card(props) {

  const [containerStyle, setStyle] = useState(classes.container);

  const handleClick = () => {
   setStyle(classes.containerMore);
  };

  const handleClickAway = () => {
   setStyle(classes.container);
  };

  return (
    <ClickAwayListener
      mouseEvent="onMouseDown"
      touchEvent="onTouchStart"
      onClickAway={handleClickAway}
    >
      <div className={containerStyle}>
      CONTAINER TITLE
        <button className={classes.moreButton} onClick={handleClick}>MORE</button>
      </div>
    </ClickAwayListener>
  );
}

export default Card;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done just  by writing some `CSS transition` in your code. You may do something like this  :

```
.containerMore {
  background-color: #05040f;
  color: white;
  height: 220px;
  width: 220px;
  border-style: solid;
  text-align: center;
  transition-property: background-color, width, height;

  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}
```

now when the state is changing from the initial value `classes.container` to updated value `classes.containerMore` .it makes this change in the state a little smoother.

I made a demo in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/momo-test-zqk0xw?file=/src/App.js) that applies How You can add the animated transition while class is changing.